# ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create database with .csv file. I have a problem with LOAD DATA INFILE command. The error is 1290. I googled it, and I know that i need to change the secure_file_priv to '0', but i couldn't  find it.

```
> SELECT @@global.secure_file_priv' at line 1
mysql> +---------------------------+
-> | @@global.secure_file_priv |
-> +---------------------------+
-> | NULL                      |
-> +---------------------------+
-> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am working on mac, and all paths that I found are for windows/debian/ubuntu. So, maybe anybody can help me to find the config file to change secure_file_priv??